# $\Omega^1_{B/A}=0$ implies $B$ normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A\subseteq B$ be two noetherians  domain with fraction fields $k$ and $L$, rispectively. Assume that $A$ is normal and $B$ is finite as $A$-module. I have to check that $B$ is also normal if $\Omega^1_{B/A}=0$. 
Can you help me?

I know that if $\Omega^1_{B/A}=0$ then $L/k$ is finite separable extentesion. Maybe is true that if $A\subset B$ is as above and $L/k$ is separable then $B$ is normal?

**EDIT:** By reading something about ring homomorphisms as above I found that the setup where I have to work is essentially that of [unramiefied ring homomorphisms](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00US). Now I'm lonking for the simplest proof of the fact above.

Comment: What does $\Omega^1_{B/A}$ mean?

Comment: The module of differentials.

Comment: I don't think just using the fact that $L/k$ is finite separable allows you to deduce the claim. For example, consider the inclusion $k[x] \hookrightarrow k[x,y]/(y^2-x^2(x+1))$, where say $char k = 0$.

Comment: Yes...you are right. At this point I'm asking myself if the claim is true.